# How to execute the sample rtems program on eclipse ide?

Tags: operating-system, real-time, rtos, real-time-systems, rtems

I installed rtems, mingw, msys, grmon in a eclipse platform and also specified the path in environmental variable. I try to execute a given sample rtems program but it is showing a ERROR has * launching rtems has encountered a problem * error stating process cannot run program and "C:\workspace\rtems\debug\rtems": launching failed.
one more question is: will rtems generates a executable file ??
also tell me the procedure to install and running a rtems program on windows xp platform ??

Comment: If you have a target, specify. If you don't have a real target, the tools that you have mentioned like grmon won't help you.

Comment: I have a target hardware but rtems program on eclipse ide is not generating a .exe file then how should execute using Msys command prompt ??

Comment: compiling rtems could not generate an *.exe file, your executable is in the Debug or Release folder and it has no file extension for RTEMS OS. *.exe is windows executable file extension. All operating systems including real time operating systems has different file extensions for their executable files.

Comment: I build it already but could you tell me how to execute it ??

Comment: which target device you have?

Comment: Aeroflex Gaisler: Rasta RC-102

Answer (score 0):

RTEMS simulation environment: http://www.rtems.org/wiki/index.php/RTEMS_on_Virtualbox. This site is very good starting point to setup an RTEMS the development environment.

Shortly,install virtualbox program from https://www.virtualbox.org/, download image from http://www.rtems.org/wiki/index.php/RTEMS_on_Virtualbox and start this image from virtualbox, the RTEMS development environment will be already installed with this image including editor, compiler, simulator etc...

Comment: If I run any rtems example, its not generating a .exe file on eclipse ide. I know, should run using Msys command prompt. Could anyone please tell me how to execute with msys shell prompt ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'd recommend installing the RTEMS Plugin for Eclipse

https://devel.rtems.org/wiki/Developer/Eclipse/Plugin

Second:
you need to know the target to provide the correct -qspec to the compiler.
Options to be given to the compiler depends on which RTEMS bundle you are using.

Third:
Eclipse will generate a .EXE file that can be used by both GRMON and GDB.
You can also use the Eclipse debugger, that will use GDB to connect to GRMON.

Remember to set initial breakpoint to "Init" and not to main and to call GRMON with "-gdb" and WITHOUT the "-ni" option.